# Which field to use for storing a multiple dictionaries in Django models?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

I was about to use
`buy_data=ArrayField(ArrayField(models.FloatField(default=0.0)),blank=False,default=[0.0,0.0])`
for storing data like `[123.0,321.0]` for a stock where the first element in the data corresponds to the buying price and the second to the quantity of the stock bought, when I stumbled upon some articles which said that it is a bad practice.

What I plan to store are multiple data entries with each one  preferably like this `{'buy_price': 123.0, 'quantity': 100}`.Which field should be the most apt.

Comment: i think [jsonfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield)

Comment: But is using a JSONfield a good practice, also I need to add multiple dicts.

Comment: `using a JSONfield a good practice` why not? json allows to use multiple dicts.

Comment: Which method should I use to add a dict in my views?

Comment: Are the fields consistent, if so you would be better modeling your database to match them rather than trying to store dictionaries in the database. (Though the postgress JSON field would be most appropriate if the fields are not consistent).

Comment: Which function do I use to add data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayField may be considered a bad practice because it uses a really Postgres specific data type.

[JSONField](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield) on the other hand is database agnostic. This JSONField is not to be confused with Django's [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) introduced in 1.9 which is Postgres specific.

It all depends on what the future of your project may be. Some people will consider using any [Postgres fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) (or any other database specific field) a bad practice.

Comment: I will be constantly needing to append data to the existing data, is there any way to do this, using any of the fields.

Comment: This will work, but maybe a foreign key with a new model containing your "buy_price" and "quantity" would be preferable. Otherwise your "buy_data" will take more and more time to encode/decode to/from JSON.


If you have a good reason not to take foreign keys into account, maybe ArrayField will suit your needs more. Your use case is referenced in the official documentation, so I wouldn't say it's a bad practice per se: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using the nested field like this `buy_data = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.FloatField()))` and I am getting an error while executing this view function statement `stock.buy_data.append([stock.current_price, quantity])`. The error says `multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
`

Comment: I never user ArrayField, I just gave you an advice on good/bad practice point of view, but following the documentation, maybe this will work better `buy_data = ArrayField(ArrayField(models. FloatField(), size=2))`

Comment: Although the error still persists, I guess I will create a new model for `buy_data`.Thanks for your help.